# Find the minimum of this function

Tags: analysis

Let $\delta = 0.503997.$ What is the minimum of the function $h$ defined for all $\gamma \in ]0,1[$ by 
$$h(\gamma):= \left(\frac{\gamma^{32}}{(\gamma^{32} - 1)}\right)\times
  \left(\frac{2}{\delta \times (1 - \gamma^2)}\right)^{16}?$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please, post your efforts... what is your main problem?

Comment: @the_candyman I want to find the minimnum of the function $h$ to get sharper bound for a function $f$ defined as the product of $g$ by the function $h$ so that we get a shaper bound of the form  $f(\gamma)\leq c g(\gamma)$ where $c$ is the minimum of the function $h$

Comment: The function h is zero at $\gamma =0$ and taking a quick derivative or just having some intuition on the nature of the form of this h leads one to see that h decreases as $\gamma$ approaches 1. What happens when you look at the limit of h around $\gamma = 1$?

Comment: @KhadijaMbarki these are not efforts. This is just a wider picture of you problem. The real question is "Why are you unable to find the minimum?".

Comment: @the_candyman I tried to find it by Mathematica but it gives me an error message!

Comment: @KhadijaMbarki I mean **your efforts**, not **the efforts of Mathematica**

Comment: Can you find the minimum value of $f(x)=\dfrac{x^{2n}}{(x^{2n}-1)(1-x^2)^n}$ on $]0,1[$?